# How do I beat Corgi Quest 7?

Tags: a-hat-in-time

In the second hub area of A Hat in Time, (the machine room), there is a computer which allows you to play the text-based adventure game “[*Corgi Quest 7 - The Leashes that Bind*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLCMu.jpg)”

How do I beat Corgi Quest 7? Is there any reward for beating it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no explicit reward for beating the adventure, other than getting to see the silly writing. The steps are:

- Go south
- Bark
- Go south
- Go south
- Talk Barry
- Go north
- Look
- Jump to conclusions
- Go south
- Talk Seven
- Enter tower
- Use sword
- Go up
- Go Dennis